# Can I change the color of a variable in VS code?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm just a beginner in development.

I used android studio while listening to Flutter lectures.
Now I am trying to change to VS Code, but there is a problem.

In Android Studio, if you declare a variable, the variable will be highlighted in purple later.

[image]
[image]

This is displayed in purple.

In VS Code

[image]

It is difficult to distinguish because it is just white as above.

If anyone knows how to change this, please.

thank you.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I searched, it seems that Dart has updated the function, but it does not apply. And the default theme doesn't work either. Material theme is installed. And I went into `Setting.json` and applied only the variable color separately to solve it.

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "variables": "#9a6dce",
```